# How to save opus file using bytes in Golang?

Tags: go, webrtc, opus

We are using pion/webrtc library and we have incoming audio track from 
RTCPeerConnection

We need to save opus audio file from RTCPacket.Raw (list of bytes). We tried to use their `OpusWriter` but it didn't work, audio is written but not playable.

So the question is how can we save Opus audio file from bytes?

The code:

```
        for {
          rtpPacket, err := remoteTrack.ReadRTP()
          b := rtpPacket.Raw

          if ivfFile != nil {
            if err := ivfFile.WriteRTP(rtpPacket); err != nil {
              log.Println(err)
            }
          }

          checkError(err)
          videoTrackLock.RLock()
          _, err = videoTrack.Write(b)
          videoTrackLock.RUnlock()

          if err != io.ErrClosedPipe {
            checkError(err)
          }
        }
```

Comment: It's not really clear what the issue is - `os.File` is an `io.Writer`, you can just write the bytes to it.

Comment: * The code snippet mentions `ivfFile` can you make sure you are only writing Opus packets (and not accidentally doing video as well)


* Also double check that you have a opus file for every audio track.


* There is also a known bug where the Opus file can't be played back by all players https://github.com/pion/webrtc/issues/485

Answer (score 2):

Does the [save-to-disk](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/blob/master/examples/save-to-disk/main.go) example not work for you? That demonstrates saving VP8/Opus to disk.

If you do want the audio directly from [*RTP.Packet](https://godoc.org/github.com/pion/rtp#Packet) you should use the `Payload` field not `Raw`. `Raw` contains the RTP headers, while `Payload` will only contain the media.

Thanks for using Pion! I am happy to help either here or on [Slack](https://pion.ly/slack)

Comment: I tried to use Payload instead of Raw but it didn't work. The result is the same. Clients can hear the sound though WebRTC in browser but when we save the audio file it is not playable.

Comment: Are you using the `OpusWriter` https://godoc.org/github.com/pion/webrtc/pkg/media/opuswriter ? Can you share one of the Opus files that is being created. Can you try setting different SampleRates and Channels?

Can you try creating a minimal example.